# Translate Natural English into Gremlin Graph Traversal Language

Tags: python, gremlin, graph-traversal, nlp-question-answering

I am doing some research on how to translate user's input in plain English into Graph Traversal Language, especially Gremlin. However, I cannot find any research papers or source code related with that. Can someone provide me some research papers or open source code that can help me get some clue?

An example of what I want to do:

#### User's input:

*display tables involved in more than 3 current lock timeouts*

#### Translate to:

*filter(hasLabel('Table').in('Against').hasLabel('Column').count().is(gt(3))*

Comment: I don't know how this got 5 upvotes, but it's (a) too broad and (b) a request for off-site resources.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate community that could answer this question?  I think the upvotes might be because it is interesting or people are doing something similar. There is a gap between NLP (ntklearn or spacy.io) and formal language or graph db knowledge bases that looks bridgable.  James, have you looked at how people try to do similar tasks like generate RDF triples from text or automated ontology generation? Google returns a few pieces of work that might beanalogous to what you want to do with Gremlin?

Comment: @Blorgbeard this is entirely on topic and is an active field of research. Note the use of "or" in the request. Code OR papers. I probably don't need to explain the difference between "or" and "and" connectors to you? Google "text2cypher" or "text2sql" and you'll find specific techniques that devs use to abstract database queries. So this question is actually very precise, asking about technologies that in 2018 didn't exist yet. Troll more